# How to mak FlatList automatic scroll?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Here is what i try i use `setInterval` function to set a variable `content` will be changed every second and i find `onMomentumScrollEnd` can get the position `y` when scroll the `FlatList`

And then i am stuck , i thougt `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y = this.state.content;` can let my `FlatList` automatic scroll. Obviously it is not.

Any one can give me some suggestion ? Thanks in advance.

My data is from an API
Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, FlatList, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const equalWidth = (width / 2 );

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.state = { movies: [], content: 0 };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=Taipei&theater=Centuryasia')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
        this.setState({ movies: responseData[0].movie });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({content: this.state.content+1 })
      }, 1000);
  }
  // get the jsonData key is item and set the value name is movie
  renderRow({ item: movie }) {
    console.log('renderRow => ');
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: movie.photoHref}} style={{ height: 220, width: equalWidth }} resizeMode="cover"/>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const movies = this.state.movies;
    // it well be rendered every second from setInterval function setState
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={movies}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          numColumns={2}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => {
            console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
            event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y = this.state.content;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell your FlatList that you want it to scroll to a new position using `scrollToOffset()`.

Store a reference to your FlatList in your class by adding the prop 
`ref={flatList => { this.flatList = flatList }}` to it.

Then, call `this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ offset: yourNewOffset })` to scroll to the desired offset.

Docs on this method are [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltooffset).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jordan , Would you mind show me how to call `this.flatList.scrollToOffset` I have no idea how to call it under FlatList to automatic scroll. Thank you.

Comment: You just need to call `this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ offset: yourNewOffset })` inside your `setInterval`, replacing `yourNewOffset` with however many pixels you want to scroll to.